# Set username and password on appsettings.json SQL Server database connection? ASO.NET Core 5.0

Tags: sql, asp.net, sql-server, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-core

Tools: Visual Studio 2019, Asp.net core 5.0

What I'm trying to do is set a username and password on `appsettings.json` which when the database is created it can't be accessed outside the application.

If the user tries to open the database through SQL Server Management Studio (SSMS) it has to input the username and password set by me to see its content.

This is the default database created by Visual Studio, which stores logins and passwords.

My `appsettings.json` is:

```
"ConnectionStrings": {
    "DefaultConnection": "Server=(localdb)\\mssqllocaldb;Database=aspnet-mydatabase;Trusted_Connection=True;MultipleActiveResultSets=true"
 }
```

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure if you can use credentials for localdb but for SQL Server it's the same as it always has been; just add the user id and password properties:

```
user id=sa; password=xyz
```

Comment: If i were to use Sql Server enterprise edition, what should i do to make this possible?

Comment: The process is fairly simple but could take time. You'd purchase Sql Server Enterprise edition, configure the instance through the installer, then you'll create and populate the database on it. Once that's done, your connection string will look something like `Data Source=<ip address to server>; Initial Catalog=<database name>; user id=<user>; password=<password;`

Comment: I already have Sql Server 2008 Enterprise bought years ago for a home project. if i want to install it on an localhost, in my office, where everyone inside the office can connect to,what should i do? I dont want that somebody physically enters in this PC and changes usernames, passwords of the 8 users.